# After Upgrade 2.2.5 to 2.3.0 Getting Error:CMS_BLOCK_STORE_BLOCK_ID_CMS_BLOCK_BLOCK_ID' to system tables,

Tags: magento2.3.0

After Upgrade **2.2.5 To 2.3.0** when i am runnung php bin/magento setup:upgrade it give bellow error:

Schema creation/updates:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1823 Failed to add the foreign key constraint 'test@test@002dtestnew/CMS_BLOCK_STORE_BLOCK_ID_CMS_BLOCK_BLOCK_ID' to system tables, query was: ALTER TABLE `cms_block_store` MODIFY COLUMN `block_id` smallint(6)  NOT NULL   , ADD CONSTRAINT `CMS_BLOCK_STORE_BLOCK_ID_CMS_BLOCK_BLOCK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`block_id`) REFERENCES `cms_block` (`block_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `CMS_BLOCK_STORE_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error was due to Duplicate tables in a database, `BK_cms_block`.
I copied table and renamed it for backup purpose and the table was creating issue , so I just deleted BK tables and the error got resolved!

Comment: No one can think of such  solution :) But Really it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for good feedback

Comment: Works for me as well.